# Cannot see pending changes from Android Studio in Source Tree

Tags: android-studio, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to be able to see my changed files in Source Tree.

The project is a git repo. If I change the file inside Android Studio I won't be able to see it outside Android Studio...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the file you are changing is not in `.gitignore` & is being actually tracked by Git?
You can verify this by doing a `git-status` on your root folder.
The `File Status` tab shows *all* changes as observed by Git.
Additionally, you can filter this tab & check your current filter.

[image]

Comment: You were close to my problem, it seems that the project is made with Cordova and the main dev files are outside the android project and copyed there on build...